# Abelian SubGroup Variant:

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, abelian-groups

Consider the following problem:

Find integers $x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots, x_n$

Such that:

$$P(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n) = Q$$

for some integer $Q$ and polynomial $P$ where for all permutations of any set of complex numbers $u_1, u_2, u_3,\dots,u_n$ $P(u_1, u_2, u_3,\dots,u_n)$ retains the same value (commutative with respect to all variables)

Can this be considered a variant of the Abelian Hidden Subgroup Problem?

If my understating of the definition of the Abelian Sub Group Problem is correct then I believe yes

Furthermore does that mean that this problem admits a polytime solution via Quantum Computer

Comment: Actually what is your understanding of the hidden subgroup problem here?

Comment: Given a commutative group operation (abelian) with respect to the variables. Locate non trivial elements of a group that satisfy the equation U* where * is the group operation and U are the minimal number of variables needed to make the group operation meaningful

Comment: Is that formulation of the hidden subgroup problem equivalent to the usual formulation here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem ?  Also, why do you think the group is abelian?  The group acting on the variables is the permutation group, which is not abelian if $n>2$.

Comment: Is abelian and commutative equivalent? Given an expression F(a,b,c...) if any permutation of the values a,b,c.... still applied on by F result in the original value then F(a,b,c...) is by my definition commutative with respect to the variables since no re-ordering of the variables changes the value of F for a given set of values. Now under my assumption (which may be wrong, PLEASE LET ME KNOW) the set of integers Generated by this F: forms a group where there are well defined primal elements (integers that cannot be formed) and composite elements (integers that are valid solutions) [continued]

Comment: To the underlying diophantine equation F(a,b,c,d...) = Q where a,b,c,d...,Q are integers. An additional restriction (which is trivial to note) is that: F(a,b,c,d...) = P(a,b,c,d...) + U (a polynomial w/out constant plus a constant). So F(a,b,c,d...) = Q can always be transformed into P(a,b,c,d...) = Q - U thus guaranteeing us that P(0,0,0....) = 0

Comment: Well anyway, a group action on the variables of $F$ doesn't necessarily turn this into a hidden subgroup problem.  A good exercise would be for you to try to write down what you think your group $G$ is, what the subgroup $H$ is, and what the function $f$ is that hides your subgroup.